# Parallel.For statement return "System.InvalidOperationException" with a Bitmap Processing

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, system.drawing

Well, I have a code to apply a Rain Bow filter in "x" image, I have to do in two ways: Sequential & parallel, my sequential code is working without problems, but the parallel section doesn't work. And I have no idea, why?.

**Code**

```
public static Bitmap RainbowFilterParallel(Bitmap bmp)
    {

        Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        int raz = bmp.Height / 4;

        Parallel.For(0, bmp.Width, i =>
        {
            Parallel.For(0, bmp.Height, x =>
            {

                if (i < (raz))
                {
                    temp.SetPixel(i, x, Color.FromArgb(bmp.GetPixel(i, x).R / 5, bmp.GetPixel(i, x).G, bmp.GetPixel(i, x).B));
                }
                else if (i < (raz * 2))
                {
                    temp.SetPixel(i, x, Color.FromArgb(bmp.GetPixel(i, x).R, bmp.GetPixel(i, x).G / 5, bmp.GetPixel(i, x).B));
                }
                else if (i < (raz * 3))
                {
                    temp.SetPixel(i, x, Color.FromArgb(bmp.GetPixel(i, x).R, bmp.GetPixel(i, x).G, bmp.GetPixel(i, x).B / 5));
                }
                else if (i < (raz * 4))
                {
                    temp.SetPixel(i, x, Color.FromArgb(bmp.GetPixel(i, x).R / 5, bmp.GetPixel(i, x).G, bmp.GetPixel(i, x).B / 5));
                }
                else
                {
                    temp.SetPixel(i, x, Color.FromArgb(bmp.GetPixel(i, x).R / 5, bmp.GetPixel(i, x).G / 5, bmp.GetPixel(i, x).B / 5));
                }

            });

        });
        return temp;
    }
```

Besides, In a moments the program return the same error but says  "The object is already in use".

PS. I'm beginner with c#, and I Searched this topic in another post and I found nothing.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `SetPixel`/`GetPixel` are extremely slow operations, which is probably why you are using `Parallel.ForEach`. Consider using the LockBits and working directly on the byte level data for the bitmap instead, its significantly faster and can be multi-threaded.

Comment: In terms of efficiency you should have used only one Parallel.For loop (The outer one). As the loop body doesn't contain a real workload the overhead of parallelization will make the solution a lot slower than the sequential version! - Also the repeated use of GetPixel is unnecessary: Use it once per pixel not three times and take the 3 channels from the stored color!!

Comment: Additional not: Wheneve you work through a Bitmap: Make sure to you through y before x! Accessing sequential data sequnetially is faster than jumping around all the time. And confusing x for y is hard to understand as well..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As commenter Ron Beyer points out, using the `SetPixel()` and `GetPixel()` methods is very slow. Each call to one of those methods involves a *lot* of overhead in the transition between your managed code down to the actual binary buffer that the `Bitmap` object represents. There are a lot of layers there, and the video driver typically gets involved which requires transitions between user and kernel level execution.

But besides being slow, these methods also make the object "busy", and so if an attempt to use the bitmap (including calling one of those methods) is made between the time one of those methods is called and when it returns (i.e. while the call is in progress), an error occurs with the exception you saw.

Since the only way that parallelizing your current code would be helpful is if these method calls could occur concurrently, and since they simply cannot, this approach isn't going to work.

On the other hand, using the `LockBits()` method is not only guaranteed to work, there's a very good chance that you will find the performance is so much better using `LockBits()` that you don't even need to parallelize the algorithm. But should you decide you do, because of the way `LockBits()` works — you gain access to a raw buffer of bytes that represents the bitmap image — you can easily parallelize the algorithm and take advantage of multiple CPU cores (if present).

Note that when using `LockBits()` you will be working with the `Bitmap` object at a level that you might not be accustomed to. If you are not already knowledgeable with how bitmaps really work "under the hood", you will have to familiarize yourself with the way that bitmaps are actually stored in memory. This includes understanding what the different pixel formats mean, how to interpret and modify pixels for a given format, and how a bitmap is laid out in memory (e.g. the order of rows, which can vary depending on the bitmap, as well as the "stride" of the bitmap).

These things are not terribly hard to learn, but it will require patience. It is well worth the effort though, if performance is your goal.

Comment: Yes Lockbits is faster. But using a parallel solution was the assignment! Recommending not to do the assignment is, well, not totally convincing. Instead a discussion of thread-safety and also of proper parallelization wrt to the overhead would have been nice.. For the latter: having many more parallel loops going than cores is wasteful..

Comment: @TaW: not sure what you mean by "the assignment". As near as I can tell, the main question is why `InvalidOperationException` is thrown. As far as thread-safety goes, fact is as long as the buffer is accessed correctly (i.e. different threads assigned different sections of the bitmap), the parallel algorithm is inherently thread-safe. Please feel free to post a complete sample implementation if you feel that's necessary; personally, I think that'd be a bit much (especially without even knowing the details of the bitmap's pixel format, necessary to ensure a code example is applicable)

Comment: OP: _I have to do in two ways: Sequential & parallel_ sounds like an assignment to me, no? As for a working implementation, I'm still struggling. I have eliminated bmp from the loop, made temp static but still get the error at some point into the Bitmap.. Of course you are right, wrt what is necessary, but I'd __like__ to fully understand where the problem is..

Comment: @TaW: if I read your comment correctly, you have made an attempt to create a suitable sample for this question, but have run into some kind of difficulty. Perhaps your own attempt would make for a good, useful Stack Overflow question. :) (Sorry if I'm seeming lazy...I just find it I'm able to more reliably provide answers when I stick to some specific known issue; if you have code that "almost" works, and want another pair of eyes on it to help complete it, it seems the best way to share the code here and get that help is as an actual SO question).

Comment: Yeah, maybe. But atm I stuck and the question would basically be the same: I made sure that the parallel code will only access different pixels and still it crashes. - Btw, @Ginko: Aa LockBits version can easily use `Parallel.For` in its outer loop to speed it up even further..

Comment: @TaW, in this moment I'm try to learn how to work the LockBits, & thank you for the note, but so far I can't think how to work it as you say it!

Comment: @Peter: I'm not sure, but I have a hunch that GetPixel and SetPixel are not thread-safe. Looking at the [sourcecode](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Bitmap.cs,e20dcc84314bbcc5) it seems that while the actual setting of the pixel would be done in a safe call, the bounds checks before are accessing the Bitmap in an unsafe way. The error in the stacktrace usually complains about a problem at a `System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()`. So I guess it simply can't be done with GetPixel, SetPixel..

Comment: @TaW: ah, I thought you mean you were working on a `LockBits()` version. The `Bitmap` class is in general not thread-safe. This can mean a variety of things; many of the methods (including I believe `Set/GetPixel()`) will throw "object busy" exceptions. Others may simply do the wrong thing. I don't believe there is any way to parallelize this algorithm safely using the actual `Bitmap` members in the concurrent code; you would have to lock around any access, negating any concurrency you tried to make.

Comment: _The Bitmap class is in general not thread-safe._ Actually I found this: _Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe._ [here, at the bottom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). But the `Get/SetPixel` methods break even when I use a static Bitmap. - The 1st version I posted does use two locks but only to demonstrate the technique. Would in fact make sense if the calculations inbetween were really expensive, like calculating deep fractals..

Comment: @TaW:  _"even when I use a static Bitmap"_ -- I believe you misunderstand the boilerplate text you found (that's the same text Microsoft documents any class with, unless it's specifically designed for thread-safety). By `static`, they mean members of the class that are marked `static`. Whether you store the object as a `static` object or not doesn't matter; the `Bitmap` class itself is instantiated, the members you are using are instance members, and thus are not guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Comment: Indeed I don't understand. When I write at class level `public static Bitmap temp = null;` this is not a static variable??

Comment: @TaW: that is absolutely a `static` variable (field), yes. But that's not what the documentation is referring to. It is referring to the actual members of the `Bitmap` class itself. When you declare `temp` as `static`, you've made _your own class's_ member `static`. But the documentation is talking about the members of the `Bitmap` class, not the members of your own class. You don't have any control over the declaration of the members of `Bitmap`; they are what they are, and the ones that aren't `static` aren't guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Parallel is hard on the singular mind. And mixing it with legacy GDI+ code can lead to strange results..

Your code has numerous issues:

- You call GetPixel three times per pixel instead of once
- You are accessing the pixels not horizontally as you should
- You call y x and x i; the machine won't mind but us people do
- You are using **way** too much parallelization. No use to have much more of it than you have cores. It creates overhead that is bound to eat up any gains, unless your inner loop has a really hard job to do, like millions of calculations..

But the exception you get has nothing to do with these issues. And one mistake you don't make is to access the same pixel in parallel... So why the crash?

After cleaning up the code I found that the error in the stack trace pointed to `SetPixel` and there to  `System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()`. The former is obvious, the latter not part of our code..!?

So I dug into the source code at [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Bitmap.cs,e20dcc84314bbcc5) and found this:

```
    /// <include file='doc\Bitmap.uex' path='docs/doc[@for="Bitmap.SetPixel"]/*' />
    /// <devdoc>
    ///    <para>
    ///       Sets the color of the specified pixel in this <see cref='System.Drawing.Bitmap'/> .
    ///    </para>
    /// </devdoc>
    public void SetPixel(int x, int y, Color color) {
        if ((PixelFormat & PixelFormat.Indexed) != 0) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.GdiplusCannotSetPixelFromIndexedPixelFormat));
        }

        if (x < 0 || x >= Width) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("x", SR.GetString(SR.ValidRangeX));
        }

        if (y < 0 || y >= Height) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("y", SR.GetString(SR.ValidRangeY));
        }

        int status = SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipBitmapSetPixel(new HandleRef(this, nativeImage), x, y, color.ToArgb());

        if (status != SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.Ok)
            throw SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.StatusException(status);
    }
```

The real work is done by `SafeNativeMethods.Gdip.GdipBitmapSetPixel` but before that the method does a bounds check on the Bitmap's Width and Height. And while these in our case of course never change the system still won't allow accessing them in parallel and hence crashes when at some point the checks are happening interwoven. Totally uncesessary, of course, but there you go..

So `GetPixel` (which has the same behaviour) and `SetPixel` can't safely be used in a parallel processing.

Two ways out of it:

We can add `locks` to the code and thus make sure the checks won't happen at the 'same' time:

```
public static Bitmap RainbowFilterParallel(Bitmap bmp)
{
    Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(bmp);
    int raz = bmp.Height / 4;
    int height = bmp.Height;
    int width = bmp.Width;
    // set a limit to parallesim
    int maxCore = 7;
    int blockH = height / maxCore + 1;

    //lock (temp) 

    Parallel.For(0, maxCore, cor =>
    {

        //Parallel.For(0, bmp.Height, x =>
        for (int yb = 0; yb < blockH; yb++)
        {
            int i = cor * blockH + yb;
            if (i >= height) continue;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                {
                  Color c;
                  // lock the Bitmap just for the GetPixel: 
                  lock (temp) c  = temp.GetPixel(x, i);
                  byte R = c.R;
                  byte G = c.G;
                  byte B = c.B;
                  if (i < (raz)) { R = (byte)(c.R / 5); }
                  else if (i < raz + raz) { G = (byte)(c.G / 5); }
                  else if (i < raz * 3) { B = (byte)(c.B / 5); }
                  else if (i < raz * 4) { R = (byte)(c.R / 5); B = (byte)(c.B / 5); }
                  else { G = (byte)(c.G / 5); R = (byte)(c.R / 5); }
                  // lock the Bitmap just for the SetPixel:
                  lock (temp) temp.SetPixel(x, i, Color.FromArgb(R,G,B));
                };
            }

        };

    });
    return temp;
}
```

Note that limiting parallism is so important there is even a member in the [ParallelOptions class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a parameter in[`Parallel.For`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd781401%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to control it! I have set the maximum core numer to 7, but this would be better:

```
int degreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount - 1;
```

So this should save us some overhead. But still: **I'd expect that to be slower than a corrected sequential method!**

Instead going for a LockBits as Peter and Ron have suggested method makes things really fast (1ox) and adding parallelism potentially even faster still..

So finally to finish up this length answer, here is a Lockbits plus Limited-Parallel solution:

```
public static Bitmap RainbowFilterParallelLockbits(Bitmap bmp)
{
    Bitmap temp = null;
    temp = new Bitmap(bmp);
    int raz = bmp.Height / 4;
    int height = bmp.Height;
    int width = bmp.Width;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size);

    BitmapData bmpData = temp.LockBits(rect,ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, temp.PixelFormat);
    int bpp = (temp.PixelFormat == PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb) ? 4 : 3;
    int size = bmpData.Stride * bmpData.Height;
    byte[] data = new byte[size];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bmpData.Scan0, data, 0, size);

     var options = new ParallelOptions();
     int maxCore = Environment.ProcessorCount - 1;
     options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxCore > 0 ? maxCore  : 1;

    Parallel.For(0, height, options, y =>
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            {
              int index = y * bmpData.Stride + x * bpp;

              if (y < (raz))   data[index + 2] = (byte) (data[index + 2] / 5);
              else if (y < (raz * 2))  data[index + 1] = (byte)(data[index + 1] / 5);
              else if (y < (raz * 3)) data[index ] = (byte)(data[index ] / 5);
              else if (y < (raz * 4))
                {   data[index + 2] = (byte)(data[index + 2] / 5); 
                    data[index] = (byte)(data[index] / 5); }
              else
              {   data[index + 2] = (byte)(data[index + 2] / 5);
                  data[index + 1] = (byte)(data[index + 1] / 5);
                  data[index] = (byte)(data[index] / 5);  }
          };
        };

    });
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bmpData.Scan0, data.Length);
    temp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: For the `LockBits()` example, did you actually verify that the original `Bitmap` is modified as expected? I don't see any code there that copies the `data` array back to the bitmap's actual buffer. In lieu of that, you could use `unsafe` to just access the bytes at the `Scan0` pointer directly, saving two blts in the process. Note that as far as degrees-of-parallelism, we are _supposed_ to be able to trust that `Parallel` will do the right thing; you shouldn't need to have to set the degree of parallelism explicitly.

Comment: _"And one mistake you don't make is to access the same pixel in parallel... So why the crash?"_ -- I wanted to comment on this separately: not accessing the same pixel in parallel in no way suggests thread-safe code. The larger problem is that the GDI+ object simply doesn't allow concurrent accesses; while you may have observed an exception on e.g. access of the `Width` or `Height` properties, it's also possible for that exception to occur on the native call to `GdipBitmapGetPixel()` or `GdipBitmapSetPixel()`. The object simply can't be accessed concurrently.

Comment: I found that `Parallel` can hog the machine if I don't control it, especially if I have another tight loop running. My Mandelbrot application uses 7 of my 8 cores to calculate and can still do color-cycling at 50fps without making the UI sluggish. Without the limit this didn't work.

Comment: _I don't see any code there that copies the data array back to the bitmap's actual buffer._ Whoops, you're right there, the line had slipped.. And (after adding the lmissing line and correcting a typo (if (i >= height) continue;) yes, my tests show exactly the same results. Of course that is hardly a solid proof, but looking good, imo

Answer (score 0):

While not strictly relevant I wanted to post a better faster version than any of the one's that I see given in the answers. This is the fastest way I know of to iterate through a bitmap and save the results in C#. In my work we need to go through millions of large images, this is just me grabbing the red channel and saving it for my own purposes but it should give you the idea of how to work

```
//Parallel Unsafe, Corrected Channel, Corrected Standard div 5x faster
     private void TakeApart_Much_Faster(Bitmap processedBitmap)
    {
        
        _RedMin = byte.MaxValue;
        _RedMax = byte.MinValue;
        _arr = new byte[BMP.Width, BMP.Height];
        long Sum = 0,
        SumSq = 0;
        BitmapData bitmapData = processedBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, processedBitmap.Width, processedBitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
//this is a much more useful datastructure than the array but it's slower to fill.
        points = new ConcurrentDictionary<Point, byte>();
        unsafe
        {
       int bytesPerPixel = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bitmapData.PixelFormat) / 8;
            int heightInPixels = bitmapData.Height;
            int widthInBytes = bitmapData.Width * bytesPerPixel;
            _RedMin = byte.MaxValue;
            _RedMax = byte.MinValue;
            byte* PtrFirstPixel = (byte*)bitmapData.Scan0;
            Parallel.For(0, heightInPixels, y =>
            {
    //pointer to the first pixel so we don't lose track of where we are
         byte* currentLine = PtrFirstPixel + (y * bitmapData.Stride);
         for (int x = 0; x < widthInBytes; x = x + bytesPerPixel)
                {
                    //0+2 is red channel
                    byte redPixel = currentLine[x + 2];
                    Interlocked.Add(ref Sum, redPixel);
                    Interlocked.Add(ref SumSq, redPixel * redPixel);
          //divide by three since we are skipping ahead 3 at a time.
                 _arr[x/3, y] = redPixel;
                 _RedMin = redPixel < _RedMin ? _RedMin : redPixel;
                 _RedMax = redPixel > RedMax ? RedMax : redPixel;
                }
            });
         

            _RedMean = Sum / TotalPixels;
_RedStDev = Math.Sqrt((SumSq / TotalPixels) - (_RedMean * _RedMean));
            processedBitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
        }
    }
```